# what is the equivalent keras function for from_numpy in torch?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I found a code in torch and I have to change it to keras, but I could not find some equivalent for some of them. for example, I changed some of them as follow, but I am not sure they are true or not:

```
 `torch.tensor` to `K.variable` ( `K` is `from keras import backend as K`)
  unsqueez_(1) to K.expand_dims
  torch.empty((3,) + requested_shape) to K.zeros((3,) + requested_shape)
```

but I could not find anything for `torch.from_numpy`. now, my question is about the above changes I did that are they true? and something similar to `torch.from_numpy`? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just initialize a variable with numpy array like this:

```py
ary = np.random.normal(size=(2, 2))
v = K.variable(ary)
```

or use `cast()` to convert numpy array to a tensor:

```py
ary = np.random.normal(size=(2, 2))
tensor = K.cast(ary, dtype='float32')
```

Beside this, the code that you used is correct.

Comment: Thank you, but I am a little confused. now, what should I use instead of torch.from_numpy? I can use cast instead of it? because I think from_numpy applied the changes on tensor, on numpy array too.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with this tensor. If you want this tensor to be updated during training you need to use `K.variable`. If it is just some tensor that is not updated during training but stores some constant value (or used to multiply some variable/tensor) you can use `K.cast()` instead. In tensorflow `tensor` is the output of some operation and it is not trainable, while in pytorch it may also refer to a trainable tensor.

Comment: Just to clarify, in tensorflow if you perform some operation on tensor(e.g. multiply)  you get another new tensor, you can't update the existing one. The variables, on the other hand, can be updated.

Comment: sorry, I just want to be sure. based on your previous code, I can use K.cast or K.variable instead of from_numpy, right?

Comment: Yes, but which one to use depends on whether you are going to update this tensor (in this case use `K.variable`) or not (`K.cast`).